# Two similar images (same res, size, etc) added in ScrollView, one makes it laggy, the other does not at all

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I'm putting 10 different images with texts in a ScrollView, vertically. It made the app laggy depending on what images are shown in the device screen. The xml code is like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- 10 times -->
        <LinearLayout>
            <ImageView />
            <TextView />
        </LinearLayout>
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So I tried replacing all 10 images with 1 image resource only, the app became smooth, no lag at all. I tried replacing all 10 images again with another image, this time, it became very laggy again. Then I tried, replacing 9 images with the first (smooth) image and 1 image in the middle with the second (laggy) image, and the app is lagging only when it's showing the second image.

I checked these 2 images' properties though, and found out that they have the same width/height (1280*720 pixels), h/v res (96dpi), bit depth (24) and both at about 40kb only. So I'm wondering why one is so smooth to use, but the other one makes it very laggy. These are the 2 images:

[smooth to use pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6llw.jpg)

[very laggy pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUZyi.jpg)

How can that be?

EDIT: I copied all images and pasted it to all drawable folders (xxxhdpi,xxhdpi, etc) and now it's not laggy anymore. Hmm..?

Comment: My suggestion is to use recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that slows down is to load a large bitmap and then display it in a much smaller space, it is far more efficiency to load it already scaled down.

Here it explains : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

It is the well-known system of loading thumbnails instead of the whole image so used when internet speeds were slower than the current ones.

If you are downloading the images from a database it will be more efficient if the two versions of the image, small and large, are previously stored in the database.